# Real Studio: How do I get the index of a substring?

Tags: realbasic

How can I get the index of a substring in from a string using Real Studio?

For example, I want to get the index of **World** in the example bellow

```
Dim str As String = "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Instr() method in http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/Instr

```
Dim pos As Integer
pos = str.InStr("World")
```